# Worklight Foundation V6.2.0 – Flexible application Development

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst

After reading the Worklight foundation documentation on Flexible application Development. ([Worklight foundation v6.2.0 Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_wn_flexible_application_development.html))

I came across this section :

> **Seamlessly mix web and native components in your application**
>
> In IBM® Worklight® Foundation V6.2.0, it is easier to mix web and
>   native components in your application, allowing you to build a hybrid
>   application with any composition of web and native capabilities. The
>   following enhancements support this greater flexibility in hybrid app
>   development.
>
> - The architecture of hybrid applications (iOS and Android) now allows
>     you to easily use native code when the application starts. You can add
>     code at the beginning of the application lifecycle, before the
>     Worklight framework is initialized, and have full control over when to
>     initialize the Worklight framework, including being able to initialize
>     it in the background. This flexibility allows you, for example, to add
>     a custom splash screen or to control the default splash screen
>     behavior, and to start an application with a native screen.
> - Moreover, you can now navigate seamlessly between the native and web
>     parts of your application without having to re-authenticate, and
>     Invoke both native and JavaScript WLClient APIs in any order. For
>     example, the following scenarios are now possible:
>
>   - Start the application in a web view page, connect to the Worklight
>       server, and then login to access protected resources. You can then
>       switch to a native view and access the same protected resources
>       without the need to reauthenticate.
>   - Start the application in a native page, connect to the Worklight
>       server, and then login to access protected resources. You can then
>       switch to a web view and access the same protected resources without
>       the need to reauthenticate
> - A new API has been introduced that allows you to easily send actions
>     (events) and data between the native and web modules of your app. This
>     makes it easier to build applications that mix hybrid and web
>     components, for example:
>
>   - You have an application with a JavaScript communication module and a
>       native presentation layer. You can use the new API to easily send the
>       data acquired by the communication module to the native layer, so that
>       you can present it to the user in a native screen.
>   - You can easily trigger complex native actions using JavaScript,
>       without implementing a Cordova plugin. You can also call JavaScript
>       code from native code.
>   - You can easily show native and web components on the same screen,
>       using this API for communication.
>
> The navigation back and forth between native and web components does
>   not require any additional programming efforts and can provide greater
>   application flexibility. For example, the following scenarios are now
>   possible:
>
> - Start the application in a web view page, connect to the Worklight
>     server, and then login to access protected resources. You can then
>     switch to a native view and access the same protected resources
>     without the need to reauthenticate.
> - Start the application in a native page, connect to the Worklight
>     server, and then login to access protected resources. You can then
>     switch to a web view and access the same protected resources without
>     the need to reauthenticate.

**Mentioned several times in the examples are cases where your worklight application would start with a Native page. But what would be an advantage(s) when starting an application with a Native page rather than just starting with a web view page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some examples that come to mind:

1. Speed. A native view controller (in the case of iOS) would be faster than a WebView at loading *something*, whatever, that you want presented to the user as soon as possible.
2. Capabilities. A native 'page' allows creating end-user experiences that may not be yet possible to create using web technologies.